# $.show not occuring before $.ajax call even though $.show is called first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, intel-xdk

Okay so I have `onSubmit()` bound to a click:

```
function onSubmit() { 
    // Grab the image source
    var pictureUrl = $('#preview_img').attr("src");   
    var modelNum;

    // Hide the containers
    $('#ajaxLoading').show();
    $('#send_cnt').hide();
    $('#capture_cnt').hide();

    // Check to see if we are doing OCR or manual input    
    if (pictureUrl !== '') {        
        var imageServiceUrl = serviceUrl + 'ocr/getModelNumber';                
        modelNum = getModelNumber(pictureUrl, imageServiceUrl);      
    } else {
        modelNum = $('#model_number_input').val().toUpperCase();        
    }   
    if (modelNum) {
        getAndShowLinks(modelNum);                           
    }     
}
```

In the method you can see that I am showing the ajax spinning wheel with `$('#ajaxLoading').show();` and then calling a few functions down below. `getModelNumber` has an ajax call in it as does `getAndShowLinks`. However, when I click on the "send" button it freezes and when the ajax calls are completed it shows up again. One of the ajax calls is synchronous the other asynchronous.

Any hints?

Comment: can return the ajax promise from your functions or add a callback argument that passes to their success callbacks

Comment: `One of the ajax calls is synchronous` so obviously you know where comes from your issue. FYI, this `$.fn.show` not `$.show`

Comment: Yeah....I figured it out.....because javascript bubbles up it was hitting the blocking synchronous call and not getting to the show command. @charlietfl this is not a jQuery $.ajax call its appframeworks $.ajax call so there are no promise capabilities...

Comment: doesn't have to be using `$.ajax` to use a jQuert promise so long as you have access to the ajax calling code

Comment: your not understanding. I do not have access to Jquery. Therefore, I don't have access to jQuery promises